# Access to path denied while creating new file on first iteration of loop

Tags: powershell, loops, file, path

I have a strange problem when writing data to a new file. I have a list of files in a directory that contains data I'm parsing and returning data with the Create-VMwareconf() function. This returns the data in a hashtable that I've assigned to $t. I've pulled the desired folder and filename from the $t function however each time I begin the loop I get the following error for the initial folder creation, the second and third work fine. Interestingly enough the data that should be in the first file is present in the second folder.

If I run the script again it generates all three objects however the sequence of the of the data in the file matching the file name is incorrect.

Any help would be appreciated in how to stop the following error;

```
$e = (Get-Childitem ".\a\*\*.ini")
Set-Location "C:\WindowsRoot\vmwareconfigfiles\"
ForEach($d in $e){
$vmwaredirectory = New-item -type directory -path .\ -name $dd -Force
$vmwarefile = New-Item -type file -path $vmwaredirectory -name $dd -Force
$t = Create-VMwareconf($d)
$dd = $t.Value["0"]

#Write contents to new file
$t | Out-File $vmwarefile
}
```

Error received on initial run;

New-Item : Access to the path 'C:\WindowsRoot\vmwareconfigfiles' is denied.
 At C:\WindowsRoot\parsedisrec.ps1:93 char:15
 + $vmwarefile = New-Item -type file -path $vmwaredirectory -name $dd -Force
 +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\WindowsRoot\vmwareconfigfiles:String) [New- Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Out-File : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null.
At C:\WindowsRoot\parsedisrec.ps1:97 char:15
+ $t | Out-File $vmwarefile
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Comment: Because of where it's running, maybe it's a UAC thing - have you tried running the commands from an elevated powershell window?

Answer (score 1):

`New-Item -Type file` fails during the first iteration, because `$dd` isn't yet initialized then, so you're trying to create a file with the same name as the current directory. You'd get the the same result if you used `$null` (or even `.`) as the name:

```
PS C:\> New-Item -Type file -Path 'C:\some\where' -Name $null -Force
New-Item : Access to the path 'C:\some\where' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Item -Type file -Path 'C:\some\where' -Name $null -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\some\where:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

PS C:\> New-Item -Type file -Path 'C:\some\where' -Name '.' -Force
New-Item : Access to the path 'C:\some\where' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Item -Type file -Path 'C:\some\where' -name '.' -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\some\where\.:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Change this:

```
ForEach($d in $e){
  $vmwaredirectory = New-item -type directory -path .\ -name $dd -Force
  $vmwarefile = New-Item -type file -path $vmwaredirectory -name $dd -Force
  $t = Create-VMwareconf($d)
  $dd = $t.Value["0"]
```

into this:

```
ForEach($d in $e){
  $t = Create-VMwareconf($d)
  $dd = $t.Value["0"]
  $vmwaredirectory = New-item -type directory -path .\ -name $dd -Force
  $vmwarefile = New-Item -type file -path $vmwaredirectory -name $dd -Force
```